# Why do I get this error in my TimerTask?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, timertask

```
08-17 18:26:44.540: E/AndroidRuntime(2405): FATAL EXCEPTION: Scheduler
08-17 18:26:44.540: E/AndroidRuntime(2405): java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: Thread already started.
08-17 18:26:44.540: E/AndroidRuntime(2405):     at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1045)
08-17 18:26:44.540: E/AndroidRuntime(2405):     at com.example.simpledownloader.scheduler.Scheduler.run(Scheduler.java:21)
08-17 18:26:44.540: E/AndroidRuntime(2405):     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

So, I have a `TimerTask` which checks all the pending downloads by brute forcing.
Downloads are all `Thread` stored in a `Vector`. As soon as the `TimerTask` sees the a thread is ready, it calls `start()` on it. here is the code:

Code:

```
package com.example.simpledownloader.scheduler;

import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.util.Log;

import com.example.simpledownloader.sharable.Sharable;
import com.example.simpledownloader.task.Task;

public class Scheduler extends TimerTask {
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(Sharable.getShouldLook()){ // Should we look for pending tasks ?
            for(Task each: Sharable.downloads){ // Yes, then loop
                if(each.isAlive()==false){ // Thread is not running ?
                    Log.v("SCHEDULER", "NOT RUNNING");
                    if(each.getReadiness() == true){ // Is it ready ?
                        each.start(); // Start !
                        break; // stop looping
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

**Why do I keep getting that error ?**
The `Timer` is set as such:

```
Sharable.schedulerTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(Sharable.schedulerTask, 1000, 1000); // start scheduler
```

Comment: *Sharable* class holds all singleton instances that are shared across activities.

Comment: After thread dead it cann't be start again.

Comment: @aim You mean after it is interrupted ?

Comment: can you show the code for each.getReadiness();

Comment: It is just a boolean which determines if the thread is download is ready to proceed :)

Comment: There is some basic flaw in your code. The exception clearly says that you are trying to start a thread which is already started. Please take a look at your entire code flow once again.

Comment: @Little Child I just mean that if `thread.isAlive()` returns false you can't `start` it again. Only threads with state `new` can be started.

Answer (score 1):

You're checking before you start the thread if `isAlive()` returns false.  There are two ways that this could not be adequate to prevent you from getting the `IllegalThreadStateException`:

1. Some other thread is starting the download thread between the call to `isAlive()` and the call to `start()`, or
2. The download thread is terminating without being removed from your `Sharable.downloads` collection.

My suspicion is that the latter is more likely, so that's where I'd start looking.  Alternatively, if you want to keep your threads in the downloads collection after they've finished, you may want to try `each.getState() == Thread.State.NEW` instead of `each.isAlive() == false`.

Comment: Yeah, I already added a method to `Task` named `getIsReadyForDownload()` which is `synchronized`

Comment: Having the method synchronized isn't enough -- if you have multiple threads that could be starting your download threads, you have to ensure that all code that might be starting them is synchronized on the same object (the easiest would be the download thread itself) from just before it checks either 'isReadyForDownload' or 'isAlive' until just after the thread is started.